# Question mistakenly closed as duplicate

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions

I arrived at [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/331885/how-to-determine-whether-i-have-usb3-ports-in-my-laptop) through a web search and noticed that it had been erroneously been closed as an exact duplicate. The question was on how to tell if a port is USB 3.0, and the [duplicate question](https://superuser.com/questions/14107/how-to-tell-if-my-usb-ports-are-1-1-or-2-0-for-different-oses) was how to distinguish between USB 1.1 and 2.0 ports. The answers on this question made no mention of USB 3.0, so it wouldn't be useful to anyone trying to determine if a port was USB 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have concerns like these, you can use the `flag` link and provide a an explanation in the text-field. If a moderator agrees, they can fix the issue for you. Flagging only requires 15 rep, so if you can comment, you can flag for attention.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of using flag for this type of thing.

Comment: That’s common. Most people (including myself most of the time) think of flags as *report bad stuff* as opposed to *flag for attention*.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the other question does not mention USB at all and even goes as far as specifically asking for versions 1.1 and 2.0 of the standard, not version 3.0.